# Data Model Design, Related Collections in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of "questions" in collection. Also I save history of allready answered question ids in User.answered array collection. then i match and list unanswered questions, by querying like 
    findone({id {$nin : User.answered}})

it works and pools objects not in answered array. but i think this is not correct, especially when history gets to large and i have to pass 300 ids array to find().

does it overkill process? 
is there any other options?

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You just want to query the questions that not answered by a special user?

Comment: If you are using MongoDB 3.2, see $lookup https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I'm using mongoose and every user has their own history. I add every question they answer in their User object. also every person have to see list which they have not answered yet.

Answer (score 0):

In long term I do believe that such queries could slow down your system.

In mongodb it is highly advisable to store the computed value itself. Every time the question is answered you could `$push` the question id to `user.answered` and also `$inc:1` to `user.answeredCounter`.

Now you can simply get number of questions by `questions.count()` then subtract with `user.answeredCounter` to get the number of unanswered questions.

Or if the number of questions do no change frequently, you could consider storing the number of unanswered questions itself to user document. (Every time a new question is added, update all user's documents `unansweredCounter` by 1.

Now this might be less preferable because for every new question you would have to update all your user documents. Whereas updating `answredCounter` frequency is far less(update a single user once that user answers one question).